# Fitting multiple logistic functions at once with pymc

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, computational-statistics, pymc

I have read a similar post here [Fitting logistic function with pymc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92120/fitting-logistic-function-with-pymc) but it seems there is a rule that I shouldn't ask question in someone else's post.

My approach is to fit 10 logistic functions to 10 different simulated data sets independently. The code written is done simultaneously with pymc's "assign_step_methods" function and sampling method is  "pymc.AdaptiveMetropolis".

There is one strange observations that needs your help. 
Every time when I run the script, there will be one data that doesn't fit the data at all. The estimated parameter seem like an outlier compared to the rest of the 9 set of estimated parameters that fit so well.

The code seems to be bug free and able to fit 9 parameters. The priors are set within the range of the true parameters. The number of samples is set very large, almost 500,000. The only problem that I can think of is the likelihood function in which the "tau" used to in the Likelihood (Normal) function may be a little tight and it's a fixed value.

I wonder if there are ways to check what went wrong with the fitting process. For example, there are lots of questions but how do I diagnose them ? 
a) If one of the 10 parameters explores in another space that results in rejections most of the time ? Is this related to the likelihood function ? Am I not understand the  "Adaptive Metropolis" concept well ?
b) Why the algorithm keep missing one parameters ?

I'm at the lost now. Your advice will be very helpful. Thank you.

p.s. I'm currently using pymc2.2 and failed to install pymc3 to my Windows platform.

Comment: Are all of the datasets simulated in similar fashion, and might you share a representative portion of the code?

Comment: @SeanEaster, Thank you for reading my question. I may have posted this question prematurely due to frustrations. Currently, I am working hard to track down bugs and other possible issues. I'm considering removing "Adaptive Metropolis". How useful is "Adaptive Metropolis" and when do we use this function ?

Comment: The very short answer is that MCMC methods use a proposal distribution to explore the posterior. If that distribution is too broad or two narrow, then it can fail to adequately explore the posterior, or take a very large number of samples to do so. Adaptive Metropolis tunes the proposal as it runs. More [here](http://www.math.unm.edu/~michele/Teaching/SC/material/Haario2001_adaptiveMCMC.pdf).

Comment: After trying many different test, it seems to indicate the log likelihood distribution to evaluate the quality of fit is very narrow. When I tried a wider loglikelihood distribution, the problem disappear. My background in statistic is weak. So, I'm having trouble to figure out if a narrow loglikelihood distribution will affect the low acceptance rate.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the log likelihood distribution to evaluate the quality of fit." Do you mean that the problem disappeared when you used a wider proposal distribution on the same simulated data, or it disappeared when you used a wider distribution to generate some of the simulated data?

Comment: I meant the Gaussian likelihood function that used to evaluate the quality of fit during the fitting process. If I set a very small variance, the width of Gaussian distribution will be very narrow. Why do the parameters for some simulated data are poorly estimated ? What is the correlation between the tight variance and the acceptance rate ?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you were assuming constant variance in the likelihood. My best guess would be that the data are more dispersed than your value for variance would imply. There's a bit in [this video](http://videolectures.net/mlss09uk_murray_mcmc/) about acceptance rate with regard to the proposal distribution; perhaps that might provide some intuition?